# PSpice Capture LI-Ion Battery Model with Behavioral Sources in Netlist

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, pspice

I am trying to use PSpice to create a custom model for a Lithium Ion Battery, specifically this one: [An Accurate Electrical Battery Model Capable of Predicting Runtime and I–V Performance](https://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/publicat/jrnls/tec05_batt_mdl.pdf)

The model schematic is Figure 2: [image: Proposed Model taken from Paper]

I have attempted to create this base model in PSpice using several tactics. The framework I have is attached here: [image: My own design in PSpice]

What I have attempted so far is to use a Voltage controlled current source for the Ibatt as suggested in the paper but I do not see how the pins connect. Current I have a parameter controlling a Constant voltage source but I want to make this model dynamically change with the draw from either the load discharge current, or the charging current into the battery. Another problem I have is with the bridge between the SOC and the open-circuit voltage, which is referred to by the paper as a voltage-controlled voltage source. I am fairly new to the circuit design world and especially PSpice. Can someone explain to me how to make the model enclosed in this paper?

I have also tried adding expressions to the netlist in order to have a dynamic IBatt function such as:

```
IBATT N1 N2 BFUNC
BFUNC N1 N2 V = f(ILOAD)
f(ILOAD) = "SOME EXPRESSION OF A DISCHARGE CURVE"
```

But that leaves with the schematic becoming undefined when I try to simulate.

Comment: That model is incomplete. It works fine at a fixed SoC (or a battery of infinite capacity). But for a real battery you need one more element: a [Warburg impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warburg_element), to emulate diffusion. The problem is that there is no electrical component that can emulate a Warburg impedance (that provides a constant 90 degree shift). You have chosen a tough nut to crack.

Comment: The circuit on the left doesn't model cell lifetime. If models self-discharge. Which is on the order of 1 % per month. Therefore, many orders of magnitude lower than what the circuit on the right experiences. In other words: don't bother.

Comment: Is it possible to add a rate multiplier that can scale the circuit? This may need to be in the netlist or a parametrized value.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for similar battery that may be more feasible or simple? The battery fits into a larger system but the charge and discharge capability needs to be maintained, not necessarily an accurate curve per say.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Either I don't know enough on the subject of batteries, or maybe you're over your head and you should step back and learn the basics of batteries before you start going that Rabbit Hole.

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right. I think the big problem is that PSpice does not have all the capabilities required to accurately simulate the charge and discharge profiles of a battery in a single model.